# How to create/edit back-end from front-end with Access VBA?

Tags: database, ms-access, backend

i have a simple Access Database where there's just one table (that i manually exported into another folder for Back-end). Periodically, through VBA code, a new table is created. Is it possible to edit/create a new back-end in a specified folder where the new table is exported and linked using VBA (from front-end)? In this way, the back-end should be already set and no further action is required.

Comment: Sure it's possible, but too broad for one question. -- But *Periodically a new table is created.* is almost certainly the wrong way to do what you want. You don't create new tables (or new backends) for new months, clients, or whatever it is, you add it to the existing table, and a column differentiates the different sets of data.

Comment: Hello, thank for your reply. Yes, the perfect option is to modify the existing back-end. As I said, I'm hust looking for a generic function. I know how to create a table from the front end to the back end, but I don't know how to link it to the front end. It's like the table is created but not shown in Front-end.

Comment: *Why* do you want to create new tables?